# Spring and mod_jk jsp source in the response

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I have spring contoller, also apache + mod_jk + tomcat. So after making an requesto to my controller in the response I am getting jsp source code

mod_jk config:

```
<VirtualHost <some ip>:8000>
        ServerName <host>
        ServerAlias <alias> 
        DocumentRoot <path>
        JkMountCopy On
</VirtualHost>
JkWorkersFile <path>/workers.properties
JkMount /app* worker1
```

workers.properties

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.port=18001
worker.worker1.secret=some_secret
worker.worker1.host=localhost
```

How I understand apache sucessefully receives request => mod_jk redirects it to spring controller.
 Question is what happens next? Does spring converts response body to the jsp page, and forward it to apache? How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Try to open this page directly from tomcat, without mod_jk proxy. Does it work? I doubt.

Comment: @LeosLiterak verified on localhost both jsp and controller are working propertly

Comment: Hmm, modjk  is just a proxy, it shall not affect processing. Strange

Comment: The file is served through Apache Web Server not Tomcat. Your mod_jk config isnt correct. Please post it.

Comment: @Stefoan i have added config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working configuration, maybe you can find anyting thats missing in yours:

1. httpd.conf (Mod_jk module must be activated in httpd.conf):

   ```
   LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

   #### JK CONFIG

   JkWorkersFile   D:\Server\jk\workers.properties
   JkLogFile       D:\Server\jk\mod_jk.log
   JkShmFile       D:\Server\jk\jk-runtime-status
   JkLogLevel      warning

   JkMount /modjkstatus    stats
   ```
2. workers.properties:

   ```
   worker.list=stats,node1

   worker.node1.type=ajp13
   worker.node1.host=localhost
   worker.node1.port=8009

   #status information (optional)
   worker.stats.type=status
   ```
3. Virtual Host Config

   ```
   JkMount /myapp                node1
   JkMount /myapp/*              node1
   ```
4. Restart Apache and check error.log and mod_jk.log
5. Check that the ajp port, from workers.properties, matches the **apj connector port** in server.xml.
6. Start Tomcat.
7. Access **/modjkstatus**. If modjk is working you should see an info page.
8. Access /myapp.

Comment: there are no results, i've debuged mod_jk and see that in logs tomcat returns the jsp source. The question is what is wrong with tomcat on the server (locally it working), cause i have tomcat configured by our it department not me. And is it possible, in generall, to dissalow jsp execution on apache + tomcat?

Comment: Yes if the JSP servlet is disabled or badly mapped. See [tomcat-folder]/conf/web.xml, should be line 225 and 360, or search for 'org.apache.jasper'.

Comment: You was right thank you! The reason was that jsp compiler was disabled see org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet, in the tomcat\conf\web.xml. It-team says that it is recommend option for production)